# SXSSFWorkbook with Custom temp file

Tags: apache-poi

SXSSFWorkbook does what I want, but I would like to use a different type of temp file then what is provided and seemingly baked into the implementation.

In SheetDataWriter

```
 public File createTempFile() throws IOException {
        return TempFile.createTempFile("poi-sxssf-sheet", ".xml");
    }
```

So...I can extend this by making a MySheetDataWriter and Overriding the call to createTempFile.  However, there is no way to for me to use MySheetDataWriter in the SXSSFWorkbook...if I try to extendt it then the package protected method...could not be overidden, because it is not visible.
from SXSSFWorkbook

```
SheetDataWriter createSheetDataWriter() throws IOException {
        if(_compressTmpFiles) {
            return new GZIPSheetDataWriter(_sharedStringSource);
        }

        return new SheetDataWriter(_sharedStringSource);
    }
```

So the bottom line is that I can use the implementation almost exactly as is, but I need a different kind of Temp file...not even just a different directory to put it in, but a completely different implementation.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your alternate temp file? Changing what directory temp files go into is already easily done with a property, for example

Answer (score 2):

Starting at version 3.11, the `createTempFile` method you mention (from class `TempFile`) uses a replaceable `TempFileCreationStrategy` that can be chosen with the `setTempFileCreationStrategy` method.

The following example extends the default strategy to log every temp file that is created, but you could change it to return a custom `File` instance.

```java
TempFile.setTempFileCreationStrategy(new TempFile.DefaultTempFileCreationStrategy() {
  @Override
  public File createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix) throws IOException {
    File f = super.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);
    log.debug("Created temp file: " + f);
    return f;
  }
});
```